# How to correct avoid this force cast

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I have this force cast:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TownTableViewCell",
                                                     for: indexPath) as! TownTableViewCell
```

And trying to avoid this by typical method:

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TownTableViewCell",
                                                     for: indexPath){
}
```

But its not correct, how should i solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't avoid it, **do** the force cast.

That's one of the rare cases where a force cast is welcome.

The code **must not** crash if everything is hooked up correctly. If it does it reveals a **design** mistake.

Avoiding the force cast with optional binding is pointless because in case of the mentioned design mistake the table view will display **nothing**.

Comment: One interesting way of avoiding the Swift force cast (which some people dislike) while you expect the value to always be there is to use the "Require" mini-framework: https://github.com/JohnSundell/Require - that way your intention is more clear

Answer (score 0):

So dequeueReusableCell is always going to return a UITableCell. You just need to conditionally cast it to the correct type:

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TownTableViewCell", 
                                            for: indexPath) as? TownTableViewCell {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely certain your cells will always be the right type, you can probably just keep it as is.  If not, and you need to return a cell of some type (like in a `cellForRowAt` method), you can provide a default value for when it fails.  I usually like to do it with a closure to avoid messing around with temporary variables or extra unwrapping:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TownTableViewCell",
        for: indexPath) as? TownTableViewCell ?? { () -> TownTableViewCell in
    // build your default cell here
    return defaultCell
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use guard.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
guard let viewCell = cell as? ImageCollectionViewCell else {
    return YourCollectionViewCell()
}
return viewCell
```

good luck

Answer (score -1):

You can use `guard`.

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TownTableViewCell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as? TownTableViewCell else {
  // you can have your custom error
  // return the default cell as method return expect it
  return UITableViewCell()
}

return cell
```

Why I like to guard here is:

It does the optional binding and so we get the cell as well as allows us to return if the casting is not correct which is really good for debugging.

Comment: Does not compile. You need to return a _cell_.

Comment: @matt I agree but at the same time I don't know the return signature of the method and so, I used `return`. If that method is looking for `UITableViewCell` as return I would. The question was more about how to avoid the forced cast and is there any alternative way to do it.

Comment: “I don't know the return signature of the method”. Well I do. If you don’t know where this code goes, how can you claim to like guard “here”?